# It is impossible to add a non-nullable field Error when extending Abstract User

Tags: python, django, database, model

I want to extend the Base Abstract User Model and this is the extended model:

```
class Student(AbstractUser):
    birth = models.DateField(default=datetime.date.today)
    street = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    street_number = models.IntegerField(validators=[MinValueValidator(0), MaxValueValidator(99)])
    city = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    province = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    code = models.IntegerField(validators=[MinValueValidator(0, MaxValueValidator(9999))])
    address = str(street) + str(street_number) + str(city) + str(code) + str(province)
```

But I get this message popup:

```
It is impossible to add a non-nullable field 'password' to student without specifying a default. This is because the database needs something to populate existing rows.
```

However I haven't added a new password field and all the existing password fields (for the superuser) already have a value. What should I do?
When I add a default value and try to migrate it, it complains that there is no such table as 'mainApp_student'.

Comment: You're extending the User Model, which does have the password field. Hopefully this just involves a Dev environment; I recommend deleting the db, the sqlite3 file, and rerunning `python manage.py migrate` It shouldn't crash if it's running on a fresh db

Comment: Alright, I don't have much on the Database either way, but what is a way of avoiding this problem altogether? I don't want to encounter this when I have a ton of stuff on my Database and having to drop the whole db.

Comment: Umm.. always test on a Dev environment and have backups XD -nah, *but also yes*, normally these issues can be fixed by settings default values or making it `blank=True, null=True` and making sure it has a value with the forms.. just messing with core Django models can be tricky, so I'd figure out the structure before pushing it live.

Comment: Two things, firstly what exactly is a dev environment (pls I am new), secondly what does blank=True and null=True do?

Comment: A Dev environment is just a local version that you can absolutely screw up with no consequences; trash the db, remake it, continue.. Once you have a production version (like running on a real server with real users) you try **everything** first on a local dev env, which should be basically a carbon copy of the production version- this is so **if/when** something goes bad it's just the dev env, who cares trash it, instead of the production version getting screwed up.. Which would be **very** not good

Comment: blank=True and null=True, is exactly what it sounds like: it allows the field to be blank or null. You could do either/or, but I always do both

Answer (score 2):

You don't want to do that. You want a User model (you already have one that Django provides, no need to extend it for now), and a Student model that has a OneToOne relationship with the User model.
Conceptually:

- `User`: models a user of your application and its authentication and permissions
- `Student`: the representation of a person attending classes, with a name, a birthday etc..., also has a `user` to access your application which is unique to them.

In code:

```py
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Student(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE))
    # ... other fields: birth address etc...
```

[This page of the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/auth/customizing/#extending-the-existing-user-model) explains it well, especially the Employee example given:

> If you wish to store information related to User, you can use a OneToOneField to a model containing the fields for additional information. This one-to-one model is often called a profile model, as it might store non-auth related information about a site user.

Comment: After implementing this, I get an Error when accessing the Student Models Site on the admin panel reading: 
OperationalError at /admin/mainApp/student/

no such table: mainApp_student

Comment: You need to make the migrations and apply them (`./manage.py makemigrations` and `./manage.py migrate`) like every time  you create/alter a model so that the database schema reflects them. Also, read the docs I linked to and remove any reference to `AUTH_USER_MODEL` in your settings.py if you did override it.